# Make a static image out of a visualization

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, visualization, d3.js, protovis

I want to render a visualization and make it the background graphic of my website. What would be the best visualization package for this? I'm mainly concerned with simplicity of implementation.

I want to make it look similar to this but with photo thumbnails instead of gradients.

[image]

I found two packages capable to doing the job, [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) and [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) and there is an [SVG to PNG converter](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5334-PHP-Render-a-SVG-graphic-as-a-PNG-image.html). Which I think I can use with Protovis SVG output to render an image for the background. Is there any visualization package that does what I'm describing out of the box? Am I on the right/wrong track?

Comment: Fyi, the above diagram is referred to as a [Node Link diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=node-link+diagrams) found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Codeigniter and in this case, a good solution for me was the CI port of the [JPgraph](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/index.html) library. http://codeigniter.com/wiki/JP_Graph/revision/2206

It creates static jpg images. I'm pretty sure that it will be able to make charts similar to the screenshot. I will update the answer as needed.